# Using XPath in XML to scrape nodes with varying values

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I am scraping webpages with the very useful `XML` package in R. I am a beginner with XPath, and I learnt the basics of it from the [w3 schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). I wanted to select a node with an attribute that has a variable value, and I am currently unable to do this efficiently. The following shows my code and the problem encountered:

```
require(XML)
myUrl<- "http://www.expatforum.com/expats/uae-expat-forum-expats-living-uae/336985-visa-overstay.html"
extracted<- htmlParse(myUrl)
#This parses the HTML data, and a snippet from it is shown as follows
```

```
<td class="alt1" id="td_post_3081025">

<!-- message, attachments, sig -->




        <!-- icon and title -->
        <div class="smallfont">
            <img class="inlineimg" src="http://www.expatforum.com/expats/images/icons/icon8.gif" alt="Angry" border="0" />
            <strong>Visa Overstay</strong>
        </div>
        <hr size="1" style="color:#068200; background-color:#068200" />
        <!-- / icon and title -->


    <!-- message -->
    <div id="post_message_3081025">

        Looking for advice for a complicated situation. I am currently in the UAE working as a teacher with a valid visa. My boyfriend has been living here for 10 years with a valid visa until 2013. There was a discrepency between him and his sponsor ($$$) and his visa was canceled without his knowledge.He was called into the police stattion without even knowing that there was an issue with his visa. He went willingly because he had nothing to hide.  He was arrested and jailed for about a month then told he had 3 months to &quot;fix&quot; his problem. The issue has been in the labor courts since then and he is currently living here without a visa (for over a year now). He has called his sponsor and gone to the ministry of labor countless times and no one gives him a direct answer about what he can do to get the block off of his name but no one has arrested him since the initial incident. His sponsor says that he no longer cares and that he would take the block off his name but it is already in the labor courts so there's technically nothing they can do. He wants to turn himself in so that he can pay the overstay charges or do jail  time and either reapply for another visa or go somewhere else but is country of origin is Syria and he is scared that they will send him there without any other safe options. Would someone be able to choose where they fly after facing overstay jail time? Is this criteria for deportation and the inability to reapply for another visa here in the UAE? Does anyone know how this process works? It's a scary situation and he needs it to be resolved so that he can begin living his life again.
    </div>
    <!-- / message -->
```

Now, I wanted to extract the data pertaining to a post, enclosed within `<div id="post_message_3081025">` tag. It may seem that this can be easily achieved using `//div[@id]`. However, in the complete file there are other nodes and attributes too which are 'div id'.

The only solution I thought was to somehow select the value of the id attribute as well. 
But again, the numerical part of this value varies. I tried using `//div[@id='post_message_*']` but it did not work.

**Currently**, I have adopted a longer, less efficient approach of converting this data with `as(x,"character")`, using `grepl("^div id='post_message'",x)`, and then using `gsub()` to remove the unnecessary bits.

But is there a better approach, please?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [starts-with](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with)

```
//div[starts-with(@id, "post_message")]
```

Comment: Oh! Dear me, such an easy solution, and on the same page I linked! I should have read it more thoroughly, my bad...

Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries. In fact, w3schools is a different site than w3.org. The w3.org page I linked to is to the official XPath 1.0 specification.

Comment: Ah, yes, I just checked! Thanks again for educating me on XPath in addition to simply providing an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I am adding another answer based on the `selectr` package which allows one to query html documents using css selectors as opposed to xpath. I find css selectors easier to grep.

```
library(selectr)
querySelector(extracted, 'div[id^=post_message]')
```

We are looking for divs whose id starts with `post_message`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to `selectr`, Prof. Ramnath! It is always great to know about additional querying tools.